# Can't cd into /etc/letsencrypt/live folder "Permission denied"

Tags: ubuntu

I can't cd into on my ubuntu machine, I can see the contents of the folderwith

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live
```

but I get "Permission denied" when I try to cd into it.

My user has sudo powers so why can't I access the folder?

These are the live folder permsissions just in case

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SVeN.png

Answer (score 3):

Despite having `sudo` privileges, only the root user can view that directory since the owner is `root` with perms `700`. You'll need to escalate privileges with `sudo su` to become the root user. Then you can `cd` into the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder permission is set only for root user. There is a way to modify the permission of a file/ folder as we required. But "**BE CAREFUL**" when modifying permissions, as modifying permissions of some root file/ folder can cause problems. (eg: /usr)

But if your file/ folder could be used by any user with full permission (read, write & execute), you could just use below line to modify its permission and continue to work on it. So there would be no more "Permission Denied" problems.

- File :

```
sudo chmod a+rwx filename
```

- Folder :

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx foldername
```

Here you can find further details on modifying permissions using chmod. So you could modify according to your requirement.
https://www.howtogeek.com/437958/how-to-use-the-chmod-command-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/live/` . It works for me